# Make index first row in group in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, expand

I was wondering if it were possible to make the first row of each group based on index, the name of that index. Suppose we have a df like this:

```
dic = {'index_col': ['a','a','a','b','b','b'],'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic).set_index('index_col')
```

[image: df1]

Is it possible to transform the dataframe above to one that looks like the one below? What happened here is that the index has been reset, and for every group, the first row is the index name?

[image: df2]

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the `groupby` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is a `pandas.Series`;

```
df_list = []
for label , group in df.groupby('index_col'):
    df_list.append(pandas.concat([pandas.Series([label]), group['col1']]))

df_result = pandas.concat(df_list).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output;

```
0    a
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    b
5    4
6    5
7    6
dtype: object
```

Call `df_result.to_frame()` if you want a data-frame.